# Finding the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I have to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2$ over $\mathbb Q$. The suggested way of doing it is to prove that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]$ first.

I can prove that. It's enough to prove that $\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]$ and that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]$. The latter is obvious and $\sqrt[3] 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]$ will follow from $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2].$ It remains to prove $\sqrt 2\in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2].$

For $\alpha=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2,$ we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&\alpha^0&=1,\\
&\alpha^1&=\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2,\\
&\alpha^2&=2+\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2\\
&\alpha^3&=2+2\sqrt 2+6\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]4\\
&\alpha^4&=4+4\sqrt 2+12\sqrt[3]4+8\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2\\
&\alpha^5&=32+4\sqrt 2+20\sqrt[3]2+4\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2
\end{eqnarray}
$$

If I can express $\sqrt 2$ as a linear combination of $\{\alpha^0,\alpha^1,\cdots,\alpha^5\}$, I'm done. I don't know how to find out whether $$\{1,\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4,\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt 2\sqrt[3]4\}$$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ but I think I don't have to care. I can use Gaussian elimination anyway. I write the matrix

$$\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 5 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

and by performing row operations I obtain a row echelon form, which proves that I'll obtain the reduced row echelon form if I want, which will give me the desired coefficients $a_0,\cdots,a_5$ such that

$$\sqrt 2=\sum_{i=0}^5a_i\alpha^i.$$

I don't have to find the coefficients -- I'm just satisfied with their existence.

If this is correct, I have proven that

$$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2].$$

But I don't know how to proceed further. Of course, I can find the minimal polynomials of $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt[3] 2$ over $\mathbb Q$ but I don't know how to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$ or the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt [3]2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2].$

What I did is this. I wrote the equation

$$x=\sqrt 2+\sqrt [3]2$$

and by squaring and cubing obtained

$$W(x):=x^6-6x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x-4=0.$$

I belive this is the required polynomial but I would need to prove that it's irreducible over $\mathbb Q.$ Eisenstein's criterion doesn't work, which means I'm lost.

Could you please help me with this? I would like to know three things.

1) Is my proof of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]$ correct?

2) How can I use this fact? I believe it's supposed to make the solution easier to find.

3) How can I tell whether $W(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q$ or not?

**EDIT:** 1) has been answered by André Nicolas in a comment. All of this answers 3) but I would like to ask whether we could know that the polynomial is irreducible without knowing that $\sqrt 2+\sqrt[3]2$ is its zero. Also, it would be to know whether

4) there is a theorem that would give me $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]$ without the need of performing the Gaussian elimination?

For these numbers it was possible to do, but a bit higher dimension and it would turn out impossible without a computer.

Comment: Since $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2$ has degree equal to $[\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]:\mathbb{Q}]$. Can you compute this?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thank you for the comment. I can't! I think I would have to find either the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]2]$ or the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$. Or at least their degrees, but I don't know how to find their degrees without computing them, either...

Comment: Have you tried to factor $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: Your big field has $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as a subfield. Therefore the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ **divides** the degree of your big field over $\mathbb{Q}$.  So $2$ divides the degree. Similarly, so does $3$. The end.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Right! Thank you very much.

Comment: Since we seem to be in a degree-6 extension anyway, I wonder whether it would be easier to work in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[6]{2}]$ instead?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for the comment. How could we do that?

Comment: Let $\beta$ be a sixth root of $2$. Then $\sqrt 2=\beta^3$ and $\sqrt[3]2=\beta^2$, so you just have to find the minimal polynomial for $\beta^3+\beta^2$ given $\beta^6=2$. Granted, this is not much different from what you're already doing -- but the polynomial arithmetic modulo $\beta^6-2$ is slightly easier than keeping track of two different generator polynomials at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an extremely easy way of showing that $\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2})$. Write $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}$. Then $(\alpha-\sqrt{2})^3 = 2$, so that

$$\alpha^3 - 3\alpha^2(\sqrt{2}) + 6\alpha -2\sqrt{2} = 2.$$

It follows that $\alpha^3+ 6\alpha - 2 = \sqrt{2}(3\alpha^2+ 2)$, so that

$$\sqrt{2} = \frac{\alpha^3 + 6\alpha - 2}{3\alpha^2 + 2}.$$

Since $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a field, the expression on the right hand side is in here, so that $\sqrt{2}$ is in here. No using horrible row reduction to calculate anything! It follows that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is in here. Hence $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ contains the fields $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ which means that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha) : \Bbb{Q}]$ is a multiple of 3 and 2. Since we already know that it is at most $6$, it follows now that since $2$ and $3$ are coprime that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha) : \Bbb{Q}] = 6$. Whatever monic polynomial of degree 6 that you find for $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ will then be irreducible, and hence will be the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about this answer. It's great! I'm accepting it instead of Partick's.

Comment: I approve! This is better. Note that $3\alpha^2 + 2 \neq 0$ since $[\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q] > 2$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Whoops forgot to check that, sort of tacitly assumed that was true.

Comment: @Benjamin : Well, you are dividing by some element you know nothing about. You could be fooled by assuming that this number "is real", but algebraists don't like those kind of assumptions. ;)

Answer (score 11):

There's a really easier way to do this. Notice that over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$ is a root of $(x-\sqrt 2)^3 - 2$. The roots of this polynomial are $\sqrt 2 + \omega \sqrt[3]2$ with $\omega^3 = 1$, and clearly none of these are in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ because if they would, we would have $\omega \sqrt[3]2 \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and the minimal polynomial of those three over $\mathbb Q$ is $x^3-2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, hence $[\mathbb Q[\omega \sqrt[3]2] : \mathbb Q] = 3$, which means they can't be in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ since $[\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2] : \mathbb Q] = 2$. Now knowing this, since a polynomial of degree $3$ is irreducible if and only if it has no roots, $(x-\sqrt 2)^3 - 2$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, hence it is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$ over $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and
$$
[\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2] : \mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2] : \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]][\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2] : \mathbb Q] = 3 \cdot 2 = 6.
$$
Therefore you know that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$ over $\mathbb Q$ has degree $6$. It now suffices to compute a polynomial of degree $6$ of which this guy is a root. That's computations : compute all powers of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3]2$ up to the sixth power and use linear algebra. I see that you did, so I guess you're done.

And 1) is correct. You can use this fact to show that $2$ and $3$ divides the order of your degree extension, which means $6$ divides it. Since you found a poylnomial of degree $6$ of which your element is a root, the polynomial *must* be irreducible.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know that the fact that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2]=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2]$ is true. I would like to know whether my proof of this fact is correct. I'm not sure whether you are saying that the statement is correct or that the proof is correct.

Comment: @ymar : The proof is.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva When you use the dimension formula aren't you assuming that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha) \supset \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$? How do you know that?

Comment: @Benjamin Lim : Good question. I am in a hurry but I'll answer it later.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Patrick's answer, the degree of the minimal polynomial must be six. This given, it suffices to construct a polynomial of degree six with your number as a root. One way is brute force linear algebra. Here is a more efficient and systematic way; it is a part of a constructive proof that, given commutative rings $R \subseteq S$, the set of elements of $S$ which are integral over $R$ is a subring.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be algebraic numbers with conjugates $\alpha=\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta=\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots,\beta_m$. Then the polynomial

$$f(x)=\prod (x-\alpha_i-\beta_j)$$

has $\alpha+\beta$ as a root, and thanks to a symmetry argument, has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. Evidently the degree of $f(x)$ is $mn$, which forces it to be the minimal polynomial if, as in your situation, you know for other reasons that $\alpha+\beta$ has degree $mn$. This gives a quick way to get your answer.

In regards to your question 4) above, it is a theorem that, given algebraic numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, "most" linear combinations $\alpha+\mu \beta$ (for $\mu \in \mathbb{Q}$) generate $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,\beta]$. But to check whether this definitely happens for a particular choice may be time consuming (though you have to get "unlucky" for it to fail).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please say more about the theorem? What is the meaning of "most" here?

Comment: All but finitely many. See the wikipedia page on the theorem of the primitive element, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: here the conjugates are $\pm \sqrt{2}, \pm 2^{1/3} $. Doesnt that only give you a polynomial of degree 4 if you apply your formula?

Comment: @usere5225321 There are 3 conjugates of the cube root of 2! (The roots of x^3-2).

Answer (score 1):

To answer (3), one straightforward way to show an integer polynomial irreducible is to try and factor it over finite fields. If you find a finite field where it's irreducible then it's irreducible as an integer polynomial. With some care, you can speed this up; e.g. if:

- You find a finite field where it factors into degree 2 and degree 4
- You find another finite field where it factors into degree 3 and degree 3

Then it has to be irreducible. This, of course, assumes you know how to factor in finite fields....