# Does the sum generate the field compositum when degrees are prime?

Tags: galois-theory

Inspired by [Finding the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt[3] 2$ over $\mathbb Q$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113320/finding-the-minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt-2-sqrt3-2-over-mathbb-q)

Suppose $k$ is a field and $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic over $k$ such that $[k(\alpha):k]=p$ and $[k(\beta):k]=q$ with distinct primes $p,q$. Then
$$
1<[k(\alpha,\beta):k(\alpha)]\leq q \quad\text{so}\quad
1<[k(\alpha,\beta):k(\alpha)]\cdot[k(\alpha):k]=[k(\alpha,\beta):k]\leq pq
$$
But $[k(\alpha):k]=p$ and $[k(\beta):k]=q$ are divisors of $[k(\alpha,\beta):k]$, so $[k(\alpha,\beta):k]=pq$

Now $k(\alpha+\beta)\subset k(\alpha,\beta)$ is a subfield, so $[k(\alpha+\beta):k]=:n$ divides $pq$.

Is it true that $n\neq p$ and $n\neq q$ and therefore $k(\alpha+\beta)= k(\alpha,\beta)$ or is there a counterexample?

EDIT: The proof for $k=\mathbb Q$ is quite long, maybe in this situation there is a direct proof? And I somehow cannot find a good counterexample for $k$ a finite field.

Comment: Found the answer, sorry that I didn't look more 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers

Comment: I retagged since the tag wiki for (field-theory) explicitly asks to just use (galois-theory) for these kinds of questions. Also, you should feel free to post either just the link that you found, or a write-up in your own words of the result, as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @WillieWong Ah, I see your point now: if it's tagged with [tag:galois-theory], then it shouldn't be tagged with [tag:field-theory]. Sorry!

Comment: @Dylan: No problem. Hmmm, let me go and write a stub wiki for galois theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer (for $\operatorname{char}k=0$) can be found here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers

and here (cited there)

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Isaacs70.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Isaacs70.pdf)

The result is quite nice: If $\operatorname{char}k=0$, then
$$
[k(a):k][k(b):k] \text{rel. prime} \Rightarrow
[k(a+b):k] = [k(a):k][k(b):k] \Rightarrow k(a+b)=k(a,b)
$$